# Como hacer una especia de LiveCamera pero con solo secuencias de fotos?

Tags: c++, qt

Hola compañeros muy buenas, se me presento este pequeño problema con Qtcreator, lo que necesito hacer es que un boton realice dos acciones, para poder hacer el "LiveCamera" con una secuencia de fotos se me occurrio hacer un while infinito que no pare de tomar las fotos, pero no entiendo bien como puedo hacerle para que al hacer click en ese mismo boton pare o haga un ´break´ al while

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi interfaz y en el boton "LiveCamera" hacer lo ya mencionado.

este es el codigo

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_12_clicked()
{
    ui->pushButton->setEnabled(false);
    ui->pushButton_14->setEnabled(false);
    ui->pushButton_3->setEnabled(false);
    if( ui->pushButton_12->text() == "LiveCamera")
    {
        ui->pushButton_12->setText("LiveCamera!");
    }
    else
    {
        ui->pushButton_12->setText("Stop");
    }

while(1)
{
    QApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::ExcludeUserInputEvents);
    HIDS hCam = 0;
    SENSORINFO sInfo;
            HWND hWndDisplay;

            char* pcImageMemory;
            int DisplayWidth, DisplayHeight;
               is_InitCamera(&hCam, hWndDisplay);
                // You can query information about the sensor type used in the camera
                is_GetSensorInfo(hCam, &sInfo);

                // Saving the information about the max. image proportions in variables
                DisplayWidth = sInfo.nMaxWidth;
                DisplayHeight = sInfo.nMaxHeight;

            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                // Need to find out the memory size of the pixel and the colour mode
                int nColorMode;
                int nBitsPerPixel = 24;

                if (sInfo.nColorMode == IS_COLORMODE_BAYER)
                {
                    // For color camera models use RGB24 mode
                    nColorMode = IS_CM_BGR8_PACKED;
                    nBitsPerPixel = 24;
                }
                else if (sInfo.nColorMode == IS_COLORMODE_CBYCRY)
                {
                    // For CBYCRY camera models use RGB32 mode
                    nColorMode = IS_CM_BGRA8_PACKED;
                    nBitsPerPixel = 32;
                }
                else
                {
                    // For monochrome camera models use Y8 mode
                    nColorMode = IS_CM_MONO16;
                    nBitsPerPixel = 24;
                }

            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                int nMemoryId;

                // Assigns a memory for the image and sets it active
                is_AllocImageMem(hCam, DisplayWidth, DisplayHeight, nBitsPerPixel, &pcImageMemory, &nMemoryId);
                is_SetImageMem(hCam, pcImageMemory, nMemoryId);



                // Acquires a single image from the camera
                is_FreezeVideo(hCam, IS_WAIT);
                int t = 1;
                // Parameter definition for saving the image file
                IMAGE_FILE_PARAMS ImageFileParams;
                QString Q1 = "/home/pi/Pictures/";
                QString Img = "LC";
                QString Num = QString::number(t);
                QString Q2 = ".bmp";
                QString Total = Q1 + Img + Num + Q2;
                //qDebug() << Total;
                wchar_t *Array = new wchar_t[Total.length() + 1];


                Total.toWCharArray(Array);
                Array[Total.length()] = 0;
                qDebug() << Total;

                //ImageFileParams.pwchFileName =  //L"/home/pi/Pictures/TestImage1"<< (wchar_t*)t<< L".bmp";   // <-- Insert name and location of the image
                ImageFileParams.pwchFileName = Array;
                ImageFileParams.pnImageID = NULL;
                ImageFileParams.ppcImageMem = NULL;
                ImageFileParams.nQuality = 0;
                ImageFileParams.nFileType = IS_IMG_BMP;

                // Saves the image file
                if (is_ImageFile(hCam, IS_IMAGE_FILE_CMD_SAVE, (void*)&ImageFileParams, sizeof(ImageFileParams)) == IS_SUCCESS)
                {
                    qDebug() <<"An Image was saved";
                }
                else
                {
                    qDebug() <<"something went wrong";
                }

            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                // Releases an image memory that was allocated
                is_FreeImageMem(hCam, pcImageMemory, nMemoryId);


            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                QPixmap pixmap(Total);
                ui->label->setPixmap(pixmap);

                   ui->label->setScaledContents(true);
                   QApplication::processEvents();

                delete[] Array;

                //qDebug() << Total;

                // Disables the hCam camera handle and releases the data structures and memory areas taken up by the uEye camera
                is_ExitCamera(hCam);
                if(is_ExitCamera(hCam))
                {
                    const char *tot = Total.toAscii();
                    remove(tot);
                }

}

                ui->pushButton->setEnabled(true);
                ui->pushButton_14->setEnabled(true);
                ui->pushButton_3->setEnabled(true);
                ui->pushButton_12->setText("LiverCamera!");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias opciones. Una fácil de implementar es usando una variable `static` y cambiar de estado y de acción a realizar según su valor:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_12_clicked( ) {
  static volatile bool runForever = false;

  if( runForever ) {
    ui->pushButton_12->setText( "Live Camara !" );
    runForever = false;
    return;
  }

  runForever = true;
  ui->pushButton_12->setText( "Stop live" );

  while( runForever ) {
    ...
```

Comment: me esta tirando error en la linea despues del ´if´ en la parte de la "ui", error: expected ')' before 'for'

Comment: Pues es el mismo código que hay en la pregunta ... solo he hecho *copy/paste*. Y no hay ningún `for( )` en el código, ni en la pregunta ni en la respuesta ... ¿ has copiado/pegado bien ?

Comment: si pero es raro porque me retorna el error en el archivo "qglobal.h

Comment: Ah, ya. Me parece que `Qt` tiene una macro `forever`. Seguramente sea eso. Ponle otro nombre a la variable, por ejemplo, `runForever`. Edito la respuesta y lo cambio.

Comment: Con razon me lo marcaba el Qt que se estaba mandando llamar, pero listo ya quedo, gracias por la ayuda