# Alguien tiene un ejemplo cámara streaming en Qt Creator para cámaras iDS uEye

Tags: qt

Estoy buscando un ejemplo de esta cámara uEye para realizar una visualización de imagen en Qt en un label.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese es un streaming directo del software de uEye, desconozco si exista algo conocido para qtcreator, todo lo que he podido realizar a sido fotos, y para simular el live solamente tomar muchas fotos seguidas en un bucle while (ver [esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/238795/38537) como referencia).

Answer (score 1):

Cuando dices *Qt Creator* supongo que te refieres a un widget incrustable directamente dentro del Designer, ¿no? Hasta donde yo sé no existe ninguno, de hecho, para desarrollos en la empresa donde trabajo tuvimos que hacer uno propio, que básicamente es un widget que gestiona el evento `paintEvent` y dibuja el fotograma actual de la cámara (está pensado para soportar no sólo IDS sino otros fabricantes, por lo que el diseño es algo más genérico).

De cara a las IDS uEye, lo más sencillo es el esquema que ya usas: un bucle que capture los fotogramas mediante un `is_WaitForNextImage`, y de ahí copiar la información a un `QImage`. La ventaja en este caso de `QImage` frente a `QPixmap` radica en poder crear la imagen a partir del buffer de memoria con los píxeles en *raw*.

```
QImage frame(frame_ptr, cam_width, cam_height, QImage::Format_RGB888); // color
```

Usa `QImage::Format_Grayscale8` si los datos vienen en grises (8 bits).

El único cuidado que debes de tener es que la imagen está asociada al buffer de memoria, por lo que debes sincronizar los accesos entre pintado del `QImage` en el `paintEvent` y modificación del buffer al leer de la cámara.

Comment: he utilizado y echo librerias espcificas para hacer esto posible, utilizando unas librerias directas de uEye, tu respuesta de los fotogramas lo habia hecho pero no era lo que buscaba, a fin de cuentas ya logre realizar un "camera Live" de uEye en la interfaz, gracias por la ayuda